# Convert array type variable to string type with space delimiter

Tags: bash, string, array

If i have an array like

```
arr[0]=2019-06-26
arr[1]=15:21:54
```

How can i convert that into a string whose value is

```
'2019-06-26 15:21:54'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the first character of IFS variable is a space (which it is by default), you can use the star index in double quotes.

```
#! /bin/bash
arr[0]=2019-06-26
arr[1]=15:21:54

string="${arr[*]}"
printf "'%s'" "$string"
```

Documented under *Special Parameters*:

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, while the `"${array[*]}"` Korn syntax (extended from the Bourne `"$*"` special parameter) would also work in zsh, in zsh, you may want to use the `j` (for *join*) parameter expansion flag instead which allows you to use any arbitrary joining string and doesn't need to rely on a global parameter like `$IFS`:

```
$ a=(foo bar)
$ echo ${(j[:::])a}
foo:::bar
```

Note that for `"${a[*]}"`, `ksh` (both ksh93 and mksh) join on the first *byte* of `$IFS` instead of first character. That matters for multi-byte characters like:

```
$ ksh -c 'a=(foo bar); IFS="⇅"; echo "${a[*]}"'
foo�bar
$ mksh -c 'a=(foo bar); IFS="⇅"; echo "${a[*]}"'
foo�bar
$ mksh -o utf8-mode -c 'a=(foo bar); IFS="⇅"; echo "${a[*]}"'
foo�bar
```

(where that `�` is how my terminal emulator rendered the first byte (0xe2) of that `⇅` character which by itself doesn't form a valid character).

Other Korn-like shells with array support are OK:

```
$ bash -c 'a=(foo bar); IFS="⇅"; echo "${a[*]}"'
foo⇅bar
$ zsh -c 'a=(foo bar); IFS="⇅"; echo "${a[*]}"'
foo⇅bar
$ yash -c 'a=(foo bar); IFS="⇅"; echo "${a[*]}"'
foo⇅bar
```